# how to calculate sensitvity and specificity in cross-validation

Tags: scikit-learn

```
scoring=['recall', 'precision']
print("-----------------------------------------LR------------------------- 
--------")
clf = LogisticRegression()
scores = cross_validate(clf, traindata, trainlabel, cv=3, scoring=scoring, 
return_train_score=False)
print(scores)

print("precision")
print(scores.keys()[2])
print(np.mean(scores.values()[2]))
print("Sensitivity")
print(scores.keys()[3])
print(np.mean(scores.values()[3]))
```

How to calculate specificity in the above code. The code calculates precision and recall. Recall is also called as sensitivity.

Comment: make a function for calculating the specificity and then pass that as a callable to scoring.

Comment: how to do that? is there any in-built function

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score